# Как в методе класса вывести переменную другого класса

Tags: java

Дано задание вывести список товаров определенного каталога. Я написала класс Food и его  подклассы Meat и Apple которые имеют интерфейсы Meat1 и Vegatables1. Как сделать чтобы этот метод возвращал name класса Meat или Apple? В главном классе был написан метод getKatalog(String slovo) который должен был выводить необходимые имена экземпляров класса которые бы использовали необходимый интерфейы, но он не работает :)  Когда запускала код написало, что переменная meat не имеет названия, то тогда как этот метод сделать рабочим?

```
public class Food {
    String name;
    String katalog;
    Meats meat;
    Apples apple;
    
    public String getKatalog(String slovo) {
        if (slovo.equals(Vegatables1.name)) {
            return apple.getApple();
        }
        if (slovo.equals(Meat1.name)) {

            return meat.getMeats();
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}

public class Meats extends Food implements Meat1 {
    String name;

    public Meats(String name, String katalog) {
        this.name = name;
        this.katalog = katalog;
    }
    public String getMeats() {
        return Meats.this.name;
    }
}

public class Apples extends Food implements Vegatables1 {
    String name;
    public Apples(String name, String katalog) {
        this.name = name;
        this.katalog = katalog;
    }
    public String getApple() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public interface Vegatables1 {
    String name = "vegatables1";
}

public interface Meat1 {
    String name = "meat1";
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Food food = new Food();
        Apples aplle = new Apples("red", "vegetables");
        Meats meat = new Meats("cow1", "meat");
        Meats meatCowl = new Meats("cow2");
        System.out.println(food.getKatalog("meat1"));
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dz.Food.getKatalog(Food.java:44)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А есть какие-то подробности по задаче? Или то, что в вопросе это весь текст задачи?

Comment: Есть еще несколько пунктов по задаче, но там нужно просто сделать разные методы, с этим справилась. Так что это весь текст :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в `Food` поля `Meats meat;` `Apples apple;` не инициализированы, поэтому при обращении к ним возникает NPE.

Попробуйте инициализировать те поля:

```
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Food food = new Food();
        food.apple = new Apples("red", "vegetables");
        food.meat = new Meats("cow1", "meat");
        System.out.println(food.getKatalog("meat1"));
    }
```

Но это должно исправить `NPE`, а вот с самим заданием -- нет.

---

Накидал примерное решение (перечисление):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

enum FoodType {
    VEGATABLE,
    MEAT
}

interface IFood {
    String getName();
    FoodType getType();
}

class Food implements IFood {
    private String name;
    private FoodType type;

    public Food(String name, FoodType type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public FoodType getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

public class Foods {
    private List<IFood> foods = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(String name, FoodType type) {
        foods.add(new Food(name, type));
    }

    public void addMeat(String name) {
        add(name, FoodType.MEAT);
    }

    public void addVegatable(String name) {
        add(name, FoodType.VEGATABLE);
    }

    public List<IFood> getFoods(FoodType type) {
        List<IFood> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IFood food : foods) {
            if (food.getType() == type) {
                items.add(food);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    public List<IFood> getFoods() {
        return foods;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foods foods = new Foods();
        foods.add("Свинина", FoodType.MEAT);
        foods.addMeat("Курица");
        foods.addMeat("Говядина");
        foods.addVegatable("Огурец");
        foods.addVegatable("Помидор");
        foods.addVegatable("Картофель");
        
        for (IFood food : foods.getFoods(FoodType.MEAT)) {
            System.out.println(food.getName());
        }
        // Свинина
        // Курица
        // Говядина

        System.out.println();

        for (IFood food : foods.getFoods(FoodType.VEGATABLE)) {
            System.out.println(food.getName());
        }
        // Огурец
        // Помидор
        // Картофель
    }
}
```

---

Вариант без перечисления.

*При желании тут можно сделать класс `Food` реализующего интерфейс `IFood` и наследовать `Meat` с `Vegatable` от `Food` (при этом, только у `Food` будет конструктор с полем `name` и `getName`, а `Meat` и `Vegatable` по сути будут пустыми)*

Пример:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

interface IFood {
    String getName();
}

class Meat implements IFood {
    private String name;

    public Meat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Vegatable implements IFood {
    private String name;

    public Vegatable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}


public class Foods {
    private List<IFood> foods = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(IFood food) {
        foods.add(food);
    }

    public void addMeat(String name) {
        add(new Meat(name));
    }

    public void addVegatable(String name) {
        add(new Vegatable(name));
    }

    public List<IFood> getMeats() {
        List<IFood> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IFood food : foods) {
            if (food instanceof Meat) {
                items.add(food);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    public List<IFood> getVegatables() {
        List<IFood> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IFood food : foods) {
            if (food instanceof Vegatable) {
                items.add(food);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    public List<IFood> getFoods() {
        return foods;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foods foods = new Foods();
        foods.add(new Meat("Свинина"));
        foods.addMeat("Курица");
        foods.addMeat("Говядина");
        foods.addVegatable("Огурец");
        foods.addVegatable("Помидор");
        foods.addVegatable("Картофель");
        
        for (IFood food : foods.getMeats()) {
            System.out.println(food.getName());
        }
        // Свинина
        // Курица
        // Говядина

        System.out.println();

        for (IFood food : foods.getVegatables()) {
            System.out.println(food.getName());
        }
        // Огурец
        // Помидор
        // Картофель
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Но как сделать чтобы этот метод возвращал name класса Meat или Apple?

Comment: @Maria, обновил ответ. Кст, вместо `FoodType` можете использовать еще интерфейсы или классы (что описывают овощи или мясо) и если нужно получить, например, все мясо, то вместо проверки с перечислением `food.getType() == type` будет проверка на интерфейс/класс вида или `food instanceof IMeat` / `food instanceof Meat`. Кст, для интерфейсов лучше давайте имена с префиксом `I` (`IFood`, `IMeat` и т.п.)

Comment: Поняла-приняла :) Сейчас дослушаю онлайн пару и буду дальше кумекать, спасибо за Ваше решение! Два дня уже пыжусь над этим методом)

Comment: @Maria, пожалуйста :) Успехов вам :)